# How to construct a REST request with username: password, headers in Python?

Tags: python, json, rest, curl

I have the below curl command, I want to create an equivalent rest request using Python. How to do that ?

```
curl -i -X POST -u user:password --form details=@/user/home/services.json http://localhost:7001/api/v1.1/services
```

How to pass multiple headers & authorisation in the request. Also I would like to modify some of the fields in the json file.

For example if the services.json is like

```
{
"serviceName":"abc",
"id":1
}
```

I would like to modify the `serviceName` in the request I will be sending. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Ref: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication

Answer (score 0):

In order to send post request with data and headers, you can use `requests` library present for python.
Here is an example inspired from `requests` module documentation.

```
payload = {"user": "user", "password": "password"}
headers = {'Authorization': 'YOUR AUTH HEADER', 'Content-Type', 'application/json'}
url = 'http://localhost:7001/api/v1.1/services'
r = requests.post(url, data= payload, headers=headers)
```

In case you want to modify the variable data you are sending send the variable itself like

```
variable = 'your variable data'
payload = {"user": "user", "password": "password", "id":1, "serviceName":variable}
```

now this will be your data that you will be sending in your post request.
[Reference1](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

[Reference2](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)